# PHP and Google Map Markers

Tags: php, google-maps

I do not know why my google markers are not showing. I am using PHP and Java Script. I checked to make sure `$DNB` had elements in it. Here is my code:

```
while($DNB -> fetch())
{
?>
    var point  = new GLatLng(<?php echo intval($lat) ?>, <?php echo intval($lon) ?>);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map:map});
<?php
}
```

Comment: `GLatLng` is v2 of the api while `google.maps.Marker` is v3 of the api.  You can only use one version at a time. stick to v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you provided, while your `$DNB` might have contents inside, it looks like your $lat and $lon are not initialized.

If that doesn't solve your problem, please refer to the working example I have below:

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
        setMarkers(map, beaches);
    }

    var beaches = [
                ['SANTA MONICA HEALTHCARE CENTER',34.0295,-118.481],
                ['BRENTWOOD NURSING & REHAB',34.0389,-118.47],
                ['FIRESIDE CONVALESCENT HOSPITAL',34.0218,-118.503],
                ['ARBOR VIEW REHAB AN WELLNESS CENTER',34.0291,-118.481],
                ['SEAPORT 17TH CARE CENTER',34.0272,-118.484],
                ['GOLDSTAR HEALTHCARE CTR SANTA MONICA',34.0256,-118.486],
                ['PACIFIC CONVALESCENT CENTER',34.0273,-118.484],
                ['GOOD SHEPHERD HEALTH CARE CENTER',34.0234,-118.49],
                ['BERKLEY WEST CONVALESCENT HOSPITAL',34.0272,-118.485],
                ['SANTA MONICA CONVALESCENT CENTER II',34.0241,-118.459],
                ['BERKLEY EAST CONVALESCENT HOSPITAL',34.0302,-118.481],
                ['SANTA MONICA CONVALESCENT CENTER I',34.0241,-118.459]
            ];

    function setMarkers(map, locations) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var beach = locations[i];
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: beach[0],
            zIndex: beach[3]
        });
        bounds.extend(myLatLng);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: I wrote $DNB -> bind_result($businessname, $lat, $lon) so it shoud be there.

Comment: So it is difficult to integrate php with js?

Comment: Not at all. So basically all you would have to do is to store $DNB results into an array and inside the var beaches = [....], you just need to loop your array for ex: beaches = [ <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($DMBArray); $i++) echo "['$DMBArray[name]', '$DMBArray[lat]', '$DMBArray[lon]']," ?>];